# Unable to get wifi adapter working (BCM4360) Ubuntu Desktop 23.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom, 23.04

I have now been searching and trying multiple different answers to this one but whatever I try I am not able to get this adapter to work.

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85df]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at cec00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at cea00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

Computer is connected to internet wired at the moment. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am officially stuck here.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for  `mokutil --sb`

Comment: SecureBoot disabled

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded from kernel 6.2.0.26 to 6.1.44 and wifi is up and running